# Excel formula to search a column for specific number, and copy cell next to it, with multiple instances

Tags: excel, formula, copy-paste, multiple-instances

Specifically I am trying to build a room roster for a conference from the registration data.

I need to search a column of room numbers (Registration!K:K), and when that exact room number shows up (i.e. 111), I need to have the persons name listed in the cell next to it (registration!a23 for instance) to be pasted into one of 6 cells on another sheet that are designated for room 111.  There will be 4-6 instances of each room number showing up on the Registration sheet, so I need to have 6 cells on the Room Roster sheet (RoomRoster!b2;b7) that will be filled with the (different) names of those who have been placed in room 111.  I want to make sure I don't have the same 6 names, but that it finds each instance that room 111 is listed next to a name without duplicating.

I can then repeat this formula for each additional room number that people are placed in.

ANY help would be appreciated!  I have a countif formula setup to tell me how many are in each room, but it would be AMAZING if I could get the actual names listed as well.  And if my request is unclear, please feel free to ask me to explain.

Thanks!

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign a counter to each person for each room. You can use a quick `if` formula to make this. Check out the table below, the last row shows the formula:
[image]

Next, to get these values over into a crosstab/pivot type table, you can use `INDEX` and `Sumproduct`. Again, check out the table below. I've put the formula into the last row again.
[image]

That last formula is nasty. Here's how it works: The `Sumproduct` formula checks multiple conditions on a range of rows. In our case Rows `2:14`. First it checks that `C2:C14`, which holds our counter is equal to `F2`, then it checks in each row that `A2:A14` hold the room number listed in `E3` of our table. IF both conditions are true, it grabs the row for `A2:A14` where the condition is true. The `*1` is just so that it returns a number to us. `SumProduct` is crazy powerful this way. The `Index` formula just takes the `ROW` from sumproduct and returns the value in `B2:B14` that corresponds to that row (minus 1 since the B2:B14 starts on Row 2).

Comment: That is SUPER helpful!  So a follow-up question.  One follow up question is in regards to the room number column.  You have them listed in order, however they will be assigned as they show up, so there may be 19 different room numbers that are listed in the Room column, however not in descending order... but instead randomly as the registration people fill the rooms (girls with girls, guys with guys, etc)  So how would the counter work in that case?  Once that's figured out, it looks like this will perfectly fit my needs!  Thanks JNevill for your help!

Comment: Ok, so I have figured out that it doesn't matter what order the room numbers are placed in.  My new problem is that the Index/Sumproduct formula is working, but I can't drag it from the first cell down to the 100th room... meaning I need to manual adjust the formula in each cell for 6 people in a room over the course of 100 rooms!  Is there a trick to copying this into multiple cells that I don't understand?  (I am needing to do this in Google Spreadsheets... which I know isn't ideal, but necessary for the application)  Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: ACtually, the sorting of the first list is important since it establishes a unique number per person per room. I'm not sure if there is a good work-around for that. As for the sumproduct copying across rows and columns, make sure that you are locking the cell references (with a $ sign) so that when you copy the ranges to which you are referencing don't move `$A$2:$A$14` for instance, should be locked for both rows and columns since that range needs to remain static. `F$2`, however, only needs the row locked as the Column must change as you copy across.